# Google Cloud Network Load Balancer High Availability BackendService Failover

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, high-availability

Anyone have success in setting up an google cloud load balancer - using multiple managed instance groups, and multiple backend services?

My initial idea was to use a backend service with multiple instance groups, and have a primary instans group for all traffic - and if that gets unresponsive then traffic should be forwarded to the second instans group.

But ofcause trafic is spread over both instance groups, i need a kinda hot-failover solution.

BR
Dennis.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a [backup target pool](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/target-pools#add_or_remove_a_backup_target_pool), which takes over once the primary target pool becomes unhealthy, is what you're looking for.